# How to prevent the child div hiding during animation.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dynamically changing the width and height  of the div. My problem is, the child div is hidden during animation how to prevent is.? I tried, but couldn't resolve the problem. I added the fiddle as follow [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRkhu/9/)

HTML

```
<div class="slide">
   <div id="handle">   </div> 
</div>

<button onclick="cl()" >
Cli
</button>
```

Javascript

```
var wid = 100;
var lft = 50;
cl = function()
{

$(".slide").animate({width:wid+"px", left:lft+"px"}, {duration: 500})
wid += 50;
lft +=50;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MRkhu/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `overflow:visible!important;` in parent css. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MRkhu/11/

CSS:

```
body
{
  background:pink;

}
.slide {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background:#2a2a2a;
     overflow:visible!important;
}

#handle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    background:blue;
    z-index:1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
   <div id="handle" class="child">   </div> 
</div>

<button onclick="cl()" >
Click
</button>
```

JS:

```
var wid = 100;
var lft = 50;
cl = function()
{

$(".slide").animate({width:wid+"px", left:lft+"px"}, {duration: 500})
wid += 50;
lft +=50;

}
```

Comment: The `!important` is important! jQuery sets `overflow: hidden` during animations.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS transition instead of jQuery animate:

```js
var wid = 100;
var lft = 50;
$('button').on('click', function() {

  $(".slide").css({
    width: wid + "px",
    left: lft + "px"
  });
  wid += 50;
  lft += 50;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
#handle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">
  <div id="handle"></div>
</div>

<button>
  Cli
</button>
```